# Now that I am under performance improvement plan, I don't feel the same anymore. Is it bad for me?

Tags: work-environment, manager, performance

If you go through my history, I have been put under a performance improvement plan. Great, a chance to improve on things.

But here's the one thing, I don't think my heart is where it should be in this company. If I am going to compare my first couple of months at this company with last few months, I don't feel the same. I feel my work isn't appreciated anymore & even though my team mates appreciate the help I provide them in certain aspects they're not good in but it isn't the same with my manager anymore.

May be I am wrong in interpreting things but I think I need an opinion.

In the initial meeting for the PIP, he told me if I step up, I will be considered for a raise. But he hasn't defined stepping up that concretely yet.

May be I have mentioned it, but his predecessor was at the company for almost ten years & he went through more or less the same phase (anxiety & stress) & eventually ended up resigning. His exact words for the company culture were that they believe in sinking or swimming. I believe I am in between, I am neither sinking or nor swimming.

I am trying to fix that but still. So my question is, how can I step up as Software Developer who's still on a junior level? Or should I resign and concentrate my efforts on improving myself & finding another job? Or should I ride it out?

Comment: What are you asking? How to step up (check your PIP) or what should you do with your life (try quora)?

Comment: "*Great, a chance to improve on things.*" That's...not what those usually mean. While all companies handle PiPs differently they almost always signal that your performance doesn't match what your manager expects from that role. It's very much a signal that you are in fact sinking. That being said, the questions you asked here aren't the kinds we can answer here.

Comment: They don't want you to improve. They have already decided to fire you and now are making up a paper trail to cover their back in case you file a lawsuit. Just start looking for a new job, this is the only realistic plan.

Comment: @user626528 I did resign on my own & ended up getting a new job.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every time I've heard of a PIP, it's in reference to someone getting the last bit of paperwork done to cover a company's butt before someone gets fired.

This is a **documented** acknowledgement that **you** are **not** performing at expectations, and they **need** you to change your performance in order to remain **employed**.

If you **do not** meet the criteria of the PIP, it's very likely that you may be fired. This makes it very important to ensure that when you agree to the PIP, you believe that the goals are attainable and reasonable.

As for what you can do about it, look at the PIP. There are very likely some explanations of what you could be doing to improve your performance; do these to a T.

If you want to remain working there, just **try** as hard as you can to do well. In general, that's all that it should take. If you **need** something in order to help you get your job done, or help to get it done better, don't be afraid to ask. **Your manager would probably appreciate you letting him know of anything he could do to help with your improvement.**

Answer (score 1):

Anytime I ever hear of a PIP I think of Amazon and the associated [horror stories](http://gawker.com/inside-amazons-kafkaesque-performance-improvement-plan-1640304353).

I do not know enough to assume your company's culture uses a PIP in the same Kafkaesque way, but assuming being on a PIP is a bad sign: start a stealth-job search.

Looking/interviewing for other opportunities does not mean you intend to leave, but it does keep doors open, and you've noted how you are not happy with where you are; can you say with full confidence that, even without being put on a PIP, you are satisfied with your current role or the day-to-day responsibilities?

I have not looked back on your posts and do not have an in-depth idea of the trajectory of your career so far. However, I too recently launched my own career so perhaps I can offer a valuable tool you may or may not already be using:

Ask **why**.

**Why** do you want to stay in this role?
**Why** do you go to work everyday?

Essentially ask very simple **why's** regarding where you are now. If the answers you have are NOT satisfying, then you should think about ways to make the answers satisfying (be that moving to a new opportunity, going back to school, etc.)

**Short here:** ride it out only if you think doing so aligns with your values and ambitions.

Comment: Thank you for the great insight. I am already kind of doing a stealth job search side by side but I am taking it easy because I am an immigrant on a work visa & it expires in next couple of months & I am waiting for an answer on my permanent residence application. As for the **why**, One of the major things I feel is I haven't had a challenge that would help me learn something new. There's a technical debt we are about to hit but that's a long wait.

Comment: Also, I am not entirely satisfied with what I am doing either, yes there are some shortcomings but I have been trying to fix them by going to therapy sessions that I pay for from my own pocket (company's employee assistance program is a joke & is only limited to three sessions).

Comment: The work visa element of your problem definitely adds another layer of difficulty to making a decision. Would you be able to transfer the visa to a different company if hired?

Comment: Yeah, I totally can since my work visa is an open work visa meaning I can work for any employer.

Comment: Not a satisfying thing to say, but it definitely sounds like continuing your search for an opportunity while trying to do your best there may be a solid bet. Try to take care of yourself as best you can in your free time (it definitely sounds like you are doing so with therapy,) but doing a mix of carefree activities with career-related hobbies that remind you why you went into software development in the first place would be good (if you're not involved in the open-source community yet, I highly recommend it.)

Comment: Also, why I am contemplating leaving the company is because I have a support system that I can rely on for sometime while I am unemployed. But getting a pay check while doing side by side job search doesn't hurt at all. I have been trying to get into OSS since a long time but I am not a regular. One thing that kind of scares me is the scale of the code base in open source projects which I believe will eventually wear off once I have adequate experience and knowledge in my field.

Comment: There are countless OSS projects out there looking for help/contributions from all skill levels. I understand your hesitation, but just know you don't have to have a certain level of experience to contribute to most projects - the big ones that are widely used and well known, sure, but they are dwarfed by the number just starting out and looking for any help at all.